# Python debug values from libary are stored as 0 and 1

Tags: python, debugging, request, metatrader5

I am following this documentation (https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5/mt5ordersend_py) and I am using a libary called MetaTrader5 (mt5) that allows you to connect to the forex marked to get infos and make trades and stuff. Now, for a trade request you need to call a function from the libary and pass some information about what you want to do. These informations are stored in a "request" dict and it looks like this:

```
request = {
                        "action": mt5.TRADE_ACTION_DEAL,
                        "symbol": pair,
                        "volume": round(trade.lot_size,1),
                        "type": mt5.ORDER_TYPE_BUY,
                        "price": mt5.symbol_info_tick(pair).ask,
                        "sl": trade.sl,
                        "tp": trade.tp,
                        "deviation": 15,
                        "magic": 1,
                        "comment": "Test Trade",
                        "type_time": mt5.ORDER_TIME_GTC,
                        "type_filling": mt5.ORDER_FILLING_IOC     
                }
```

To send the trade I simply call the function "send_order":

```
def send_order(self, request):
    order_request = mt5.order_send(request)
    return order_request
```

The problem is that I can see in the debugger that the values in the request dict that are from the libary like "action", "type", "price", "type_time", "type_filling" are stored as 0 and 1. I think that this is the reason why my trades are not executed. Do you know why they are stored as 0 and 1 in the debugger? The variable "order_request" is always "0".

Thank you already!

Comment: Only in the debugger? If you do `print(request)`  in the script you see the expected values?

Comment: If I do print(request) the values are also 0 and 1.

Comment: Then maybe those are just the values of the constants. Look at the source code to see their values.

Comment: They are. Ok, I didn't know that this is a way you would do that. Thank you for the information. So that is not the reason why my trades are not executed hehe... I'll keep looking